# datatables searchbuilder this.popover is not a function

Tags: jquery, datatables

```
<script src="Scripts/datatables.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.dataTables.min.js">
<script src="Scripts/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/dataTables.dateTime.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/searchBuilder.bootstrap.js"></script>



$('#tblData').DataTable
                                    (
                                        {
                                            retrieve: true,
                                            scrollY: '56vh',
                                            scrollX: false,
                                            //"pageLength": 15,
                                            "iDisplayLength": 30,
                                            //scrollX: false,
                                            scrollCollapse: true,
                                            //"order": [0, "asc"],
                                            //"ordering": false,
                                            //"pagingType": "full_numbers"

                                            paging: false
                                            //for PDF
                                            , dom: 'Bfrtip',
                                            buttons:
                                            [
                                                //'copyHtml5',
                                                //'excelHtml5',
                                                //'csvHtml5',
                                                //'pdfHtml5',

                                                {
                                                    extend: 'copyHtml5',
                                                    messageTop: 'As On: ' + customMessage
                                                },

                                                {
                                                    extend: 'excelHtml5',
                                                    messageTop: 'As On: ' + customMessage
                                                }
                                                ,
                                                {
                                                    extend: 'csvHtml5',
                                                    messageTop: 'As On: ' + customMessage
                                                }
                                                ,
                                                {
                                                    extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                                                    messageTop: 'As On: ' + customMessage
                                                }
                                                ,
                                                {
                                                    extend: 'searchBuilder',
                                                    config: {
                                                        depthLimit: 2
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            ]
                                            //for export Options Ends here.
                                        }
                                      );
```

The Search Builder button shows with other buttons, But when click on SearchBuilder button it fires error:

> dataTables.searchBuilder.min.js:136 Uncaught TypeError: this.popover is not a function
> at s.action (dataTables.searchBuilder.min.js:136:109)
> at v (index.js:22:1)
> at HTMLButtonElement. (index.js:22:1)
> at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery-3.5.1.js:5429:27)
> at elemData.handle (jquery-3.5.1.js:5233:28) action @ dataTables.searchBuilder.min.js:136 v @ index.js:22 (anonymous) @
> index.js:22 dispatch @ jquery-3.5.1.js:5429 elemData.handle @
> jquery-3.5.1.js:5233

Comment: We have no idea what is in any of those JS libraries you show in your code. But I can say it looks as if you are missing the core `dataTables.searchBuilder.js` library. You need that in addition to the Bootstrap SearchBuilder library. Go to the official [downloads page](https://datatables.net/download), select all the downloads you need, and then try again with those.

Comment: andrew, I've included that core library, But still the error is not resolved... :(

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add searchBuilder to [buttons](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/). Datatables make use of https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom.
Meaning your `dom: 'Bfrtip',` is missing the Q plugin.

**Answer:** dom: QlBfrtip,